# CUPS spooling/server

Tags: 12.04, updates, printing

I have updated my Ubuntu System 12.04 after fresh installation. The Update run well. After I shut down the PC I saw messages like:

```
Checking battery status [OK]
```

And some more messages, what I do not understand is
`Starting CUPS spooler/server [OK]` or maybe `Stopping` - I am not sure.
I tried to Google it and it seems that it has to do something with the printer?
I did not print anything or add printers or something like this and this really is a strange message. 
Is it OK that I saw this message?

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry, it is entirely alright. The CUPS printer/spooler is a background process which runs regardless of whether you have defined a printer.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to disable cups services, do the following:

```
System Settings > Preferences > Sessions
uncheck the Printing Services.
```